# Customized hash for nested attributes errors in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise-token-auth, accepts-nested-attributes

I have addresses & phones associations against the user model which means that a user can have multiple addresses and multiple phones.

I have to store 1 address and 1 phone at the time of signup where I am using devise_token_auth gem.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :phones, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up,
    keys: [
      :email,
      :name,
      addresses_attributes: %i[street_1 street_2 city state country zip label default],
      phones_attributes: %i[label dial default]
    ]
  )
end
```

**Problem**

If I send the address and phone attributes empty/invalid, I am receiving the error JSON as follows:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        ...
    },
    "errors": {
        "addresses.label": [
            "can't be blank"
        ],
        "addresses.street_1": [
            "can't be blank"
        ],
        "addresses.city": [
            "can't be blank"
        ],
        "phones.dial": [
            "Not a valid 10-digit telephone number"
        ],
        "full_messages": [
            "Addresses label can't be blank",
            "Addresses street 1 can't be blank",
            "Addresses city can't be blank",
            "Phones dial Not a valid 10-digit telephone number",
        ]
    }
}
```

Following the article [Errors can be indexed with nested attributes in Rails 5](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/07/errors-can-be-indexed-with-nested-attrbutes-in-rails-5.html) by using `index_errors: true`, I am receiving the error JSON as:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        ...
    },
    "errors": {
        "addresses[0].label": [
            "can't be blank"
        ],
        "addresses[0].street_1": [
            "can't be blank"
        ],
        "addresses[0].city": [
            "can't be blank"
        ],
        "phones[0].dial": [
            "Not a valid 10-digit telephone number"
        ],
        "full_messages": [
            "Addresses[0] label can't be blank",
            "Addresses[0] street 1 can't be blank",
            "Addresses[0] city can't be blank",
            "Phones[0] dial Not a valid 10-digit telephone number",
        ]
    }
}
```

What I really need is something like following which I can easily traverse in any language:

```
errors: {
   addresses: {
      label: ["can't be blank"],
      street_1: ["can't be blank"],
      ...
   },
   phones: {
      dial: ["Not a valid 10-digit telephone number"]
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything keeping you from simply using `map` or `each_with_object` to turn your errors into the desired structure?

Comment: I am a massive fan of the RABL gem when it comes to formatting JSON in Rails https://github.com/nesquena/rabl an ols railscast also covers it's usage here http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl?autoplay=true